# Two different django apps with different authentications in the same project

Tags: django

Please I want to create two different apps in django with two different authentications. I have Personal Assistant app and Accountant app. I want the Personal Assistant page to be different from Accountant Page. Please how should I go about creating different authentication for Accountant app?

Login for personal assistant
'''
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout

def loginPage(request):

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    username = request.POST.get('username')
    password = request.POST.get('password')

    user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)

    if user is not None:
        login(request, user)
        return redirect('index')
    else:
        messages.info(request, 'Username OR password is incorrect')

context = {}
return render(request, 'app/login.html', context)
```

'''

Because I don't want

Comment: Why don't you use the same login system and just separate them by django groups and permissions?

Comment: Ohh okay. I will try that too thanks.